# If I combine a Nvidia 1080 with an extra 1070, does it make a difference with movies?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I currently have an i7-8700k @ 3.7 with an Nvidia 1080 and 2 monitors: a 4k monitor (3840x2160) and a second monitor (2560x1600).  I play movies with Potplayer with MadVR on the 4k monitor.  I apparently can't play movies with all the MadVR settings that I want.  I have to compromise a lot or the movies start to stutter.  There doesn't seem to be an expert guide out there that tells you the best settings although there are several unofficial guides in which the authors tell you what they've been using.  The guides all vary bit, sometimes quite a bit.

In order to use more of the MadVR settings, I was thinking about adding an extra graphics card that I have lying around.  My motherboard is able to do it.  I want to add a Nvidia 1070 that I have lying around.  Will it allow me to increase the settings of the MadVR?

Comment: No it won’t. But the question in the first place is whether it is actually the GPU that is limiting performance here. How did you determine this?

Comment: I have no idea.  When I decrease settings such as anti-aliasing from high quality, the stuttering stops.  What other computer component would be involved?  The CPU?  It's not the memory as I have 32 gigs of it.  Using taskmaster is not help as nothing is close to max except the GPU power.  I have no idea that that means.  It's always the GPU power that gets really high.

Comment: Running your cards in SLI would result in worse performance not better and I doubt these applications support mGPU features of DX12 and Vulcan

Comment: Ramhound, are you sure?  On the internet, I read conflicting info.  Some say what you say and others say that it would help.